# How to get images out from a GIF file from project

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, animated-gif

I have a GIF in my project and I want to get all the images of GIF in an array.
I am using this to create an imageview and animate at my ease.

```
- (UIImageView *)createImageViewWith:(NSData *)data frame:(CGRect)rect bAnimate:(BOOL)flag withAnimation:(BOOL)shouldAnimate {
    CGImageSourceRef srcImage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFTypeRef) data, nil);
    if (!srcImage) {
        NSLog(@"loading image failed");
    }

    size_t imgCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(srcImage);
    NSTimeInterval totalDuration = 0;
    NSNumber *frameDuration;
    NSMutableArray *arrayImages;

    arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < imgCount; i ++) {
        CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(srcImage, i, nil);
        if (!cgImg) {
            NSLog(@"loading %ldth image failed from the source", (long)i);
            continue;
        }

        UIImage *img = [self scaledImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg] size:rect.size];
        [arrayImages addObject:img];

        NSDictionary *property = CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(srcImage, i, nil));
        NSDictionary *gifDict = property[(__bridge id) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

        frameDuration = gifDict[(__bridge id) kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
        if (!frameDuration) {
            frameDuration = gifDict[(__bridge id) kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
        }

        totalDuration += frameDuration.floatValue;

        CGImageRelease(cgImg);
    }

    if (srcImage != nil) {
        CFRelease(srcImage);
    }

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imgView.image = arrayImages.firstObject;
    imgView.autoresizingMask = 0B11111;
    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    imgView.animationImages = arrayImages;
    imgView.animationDuration = totalDuration;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount = (flag == YES? 0 : 1);
    if (shouldAnimate) {
        [imgView startAnimating];
    }

    return imgView;
}
```

This code is taking lots of time to get the images out and get a final usable imageview.
For example, this code takes about 4 seconds to load a gif of about 120 images which animate fully in 4-5 seconds.

Is there any other way to get the images out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to get the images out.

Yes.

You might want to try a third-party GIF decoder. [This one](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load), for example, is nothing more than a C/ObjC header. Just include it into your project, define a frame writer callback and call the decoding function.